# DynamoDB Table Partition key and sort key are 1:1 - how to go about querying only using partition key?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am attempting to query a table that has a partition key and sort key (however the partition key and sort key are 1:1 and I want to query only using the partition key [in which only one item would be returned]).

```
        QueryRequest query = new QueryRequest()
            .withTableName(TABLE_NAME)
            .withKeyConditionExpression("testId = :" + "1234567890");

    QueryResult result = client.query(query);
```

This is the code I tried but it did not work (testId is the partition key name and 1234567890 is the partition key value in String form); do y'all know of a method I could use to query by only using the partition key keeping in mind that only one item will be returned since the partition key and sort key are 1:1? Thank you so much in advance. [This is my first Stack Overflow post - my apologies if I worded things poorly, I'm happy to answer any questions about my wording]

FYI: this is the error statement I got when trying to use the code above:

```
errorMessage": "Invalid KeyConditionExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

You should really update to use A**WS SDK For Java V2** (Using AWS SDK for V1 is not best practice). Using AWS SDK for Java v2 is best practice for using Amazon DynamoDB API.

To learn more about the AWS V2 Java API, read the Developer Guide here.

[Developer guide - AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

Now I will answer this question with V2.  The solution that worked for me was create a secondary index named **year-index**. This uses just my partition key named **year** (and does not use the sort key).

I can successfully query using this index, as shown here that uses the **AWS Management Console**.

Now only movies with the year 2014 are returned. That is how you query when your table has a composite key made up of a partition key and sort key and you only want to query on partition key.

**By the way - you said you have a secondary index. A table can have more then 1 secondary index**

[image]

**Code that you need for V2 to query a secondary Index**

I will show you how to use V2 to search for secondary index using three ways.

**First way - Use the V2 Enhanced Client**
Once you create the secondary index, you can use it to query. As mentioned, I created a secondary index named **year-index**. I can use this secondary index to query data by using the [DynamoDB Enhanced Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/DynamoDbEnhancedClient.html).

Because, I am querying the **Movies** table, I have to create a Class named **Movies** like this. Notice the use of the **@DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey** annotation.

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbBean;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbPartitionKey;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbSortKey;

@DynamoDbBean
public class Movies {
    private String title;
    private int year;
    private String info;

    @DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey(indexNames = { "year-index" })
    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    public int getYear() {
      return this.year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @DynamoDbSortKey
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return this.info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the V2 code that lets you query using the secondary index.

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.get_item_index.import]

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.pagination.sync.SdkIterable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbIndex;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.Key;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.Page;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.QueryConditional;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.QueryEnhancedRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;

import java.util.List;
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.get_item_index.import]


/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 *
 * To get an item from an Amazon DynamoDB table using the AWS SDK for Java V2, its better practice to use the
 * Enhanced Client, see the EnhancedGetItem example.
 *
 *  Create the Movies table by running the Scenario example and loading the Movies data from the JSON file. Next create a secondary
 *  index for the Movies table that uses only the year column. Name the index **year-index**. For more information, see:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html
 */
public class EnhancedGetItemUsingIndex {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                String tableName = "Movies" ; //args[0];
                ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
                Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
                DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                        .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                        .region(region)
                        .build();

                queryIndex(ddb, tableName);
                ddb.close();
        }

        // snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.get_item_index.main]
        public static void queryIndex(DynamoDbClient ddb, String tableName) {

                try {
                        // Create a DynamoDbEnhancedClient and use the DynamoDbClient object.
                        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                                .dynamoDbClient(ddb)
                                .build();

                        //Create a DynamoDbTable object based on Movies.
                        DynamoDbTable<Movies> table = enhancedClient.table("Movies", TableSchema.fromBean(Movies.class));
                        String dateVal = "2013";

                        DynamoDbIndex<Movies> secIndex =
                                enhancedClient.table("Movies", TableSchema.fromBean(Movies.class))
                                        .index("year-index");

                        AttributeValue attVal = AttributeValue.builder()
                                .n(dateVal)
                                .build();

                        // Create a QueryConditional object that's used in the query operation.
                        QueryConditional queryConditional = QueryConditional
                                .keyEqualTo(Key.builder().partitionValue(attVal)
                                        .build());

                        // Get items in the table.
                        SdkIterable<Page<Movies>> results =  secIndex.query(
                                QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
                                        .queryConditional(queryConditional)
                                        .limit(300)
                                        .build());

                        //Display the results.
                        results.forEach(page -> {
                                List<Movies> allMovies =  page.items();
                                for (Movies myMovies: allMovies) {
                                        System.out.println("The movie title is " + myMovies.getTitle() + ". The year is " + myMovies.getYear());
                                }
                        });

                } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                        System.exit(1);
                }
        }

        // snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.get_item_index.main]
}
```

This now returns all Movies where the year is 2013.

[image]

**Second way - Use the V2 Service Client**

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.query_items_sec_index.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.QueryRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.QueryResponse;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.query_items_sec_index.import]


/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 *
 * Create the Movies table by running the Scenario example and loading the Movies data from the JSON file. Next create a secondary
 * index for the Movies table that uses only the year column. Name the index **year-index**. For more information, see:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html
 */
public class QueryItemsUsingIndex {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                String tableName = "Movies" ; //args[0];
                ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
                Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
                DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                        .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                        .region(region)
                        .build();

                queryIndex(ddb, tableName);
                ddb.close();
        }

        // snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.query_items_sec_index.main]
        public static void queryIndex(DynamoDbClient ddb, String tableName) {

                try {
                        Map<String,String> expressionAttributesNames = new HashMap<>();
                        expressionAttributesNames.put("#year","year");

                        Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
                        expressionAttributeValues.put(":yearValue", AttributeValue.builder().n("2013").build());

                        QueryRequest request = QueryRequest.builder()
                                .tableName(tableName)
                                .indexName("year-index")
                                .keyConditionExpression("#year = :yearValue")
                                .expressionAttributeNames(expressionAttributesNames)
                                .expressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues)
                                .build();

                        System.out.println("=== Movie Titles ===");

                        QueryResponse response = ddb.query(request);
                        response.items()
                                .forEach(movie-> System.out.println(movie.get("title").s()));


                } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                        System.exit(1);
                }
        }
        // snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.query_items_sec_index.main]
}
```

****Third way - Use PartQL**

Of course, you can query the partition key using PartiQL. For example.

```
public static void queryTable(DynamoDbClient ddb) {
        String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM MoviesPartiQ where year = ? ORDER BY info";
        try {

            List<AttributeValue> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
            AttributeValue att1 = AttributeValue.builder()
                    .n(String.valueOf("2013"))
                    .build();
            parameters.add(att1);

            // Get items in the table and write out the ID value.
            ExecuteStatementResponse response = executeStatementRequest(ddb, sqlStatement, parameters);
            System.out.println("ExecuteStatement successful: "+ response.toString());

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you may have misread my post - the table I am attempting to query does indeed have a partition key and sort key, however these keys are 1:1 so if I query any given partition key value, only one value will be returned. With that being said, I only want to query using the partition key and not the composite key.

Comment: Your wording was not 100% clear to me. Anyhow - if a table has a composite key (partition and sort key) and you attempt to query only part of that key (ie- just using partition key and not sort key) - you will get an exception that states: The provided key element does not match the schema. The solution here is use  a global secondary index.

Comment: The table already has a global secondary index which happens to be the sort key that I do not want to query using. Since my wording was not clear, allow me to try to reword it: my table has a partition key and sort key that are 1:1 in which each partition key value will return one and only one value. As far as I'm concerned GetItem does not work in this case because as far as I'm concerned Query API must be used if I'm only trying to query using the partition key. I tried to use GetItem prior but like you said, it prompted me saying that the key element did not match the schema.

Comment: So do a query, and don't specify a Sort Key constraint. The RCU cost is the same. The performance is going to be almost exactly the same too. Which is faster, to fetch a single specific value from a b-tree holding a single value or to fetch all values from a b-tree holding a single value? Let's call it a tie. So keep calm and Query on!

Comment: "The table already has a global secondary index which happens to be the sort key". Create a second GSI based on the partition key you want to search on.